# Call a javascript function dynamically from controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, arrays, autocomplete

I am using jquery autocomple mechanism. It needs an array on which this javascript will run and show the result on typing.Thats why I need the availableTags array. But problem is that javascript is loading only the time of page loading and it is capturing the initial array but I need the javascript to be called dynamically during the type of each keyword typing...so how can I resolve this?

Actually I want to call this javascript function from my controller function.

My controller code is:

```
class EmployeesController < ApplicationController
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

def new
    @emp=Employee.new
    @emps=Employee.all

 @check=params[:pt]
 puts @check
 x_dynamic=check_ultimate(@check)
 puts "return value"
 puts x_dynamic

 y=string_include(x_dynamic,@emps)
 puts y
 end

 def string_include(substring,data_ref)
 loo=0
 @firstname_array=Array.new

 data_ref.each do |d_ref|  
    puts "in the loop of string_include method"
    my_string=d_ref.compact_string

    if my_string.include? substring
        puts "String "+ my_string+" includes "+substring
        loo=loo+1
        puts loo
        puts d_ref.firstname
        @firstname_array && @firstname_array.push(d_ref.firstname)
    end

 end
 puts "This is the array"
 puts @firstname_array
 return 1
 end

 def create
    @emp=Employee.new(u_params)

  ret_val=string_check(params[:employee][:firstname])
    if ret_val == 1
  ret_one=convert(params[:employee][:firstname],@emp)
  if ret_one == 1
          @emp.save
          redirect_to new_employee_path , :notice => "Inserted!!!" 
  end
    elsif ret_val == 0
        redirect_to new_employee_path , :notice => "Match,Not inserted!!!"

  else
        redirect_to new_employee_path , :notice => ret_val.to_s
  end
  end


  def u_params
  params.require(:employee).permit(:firstname)
  end

  def convert(entered_name,ref)

  count =0
  txt=entered_name.chomp
  size1=txt.to_s.length

  arr1=Array.new
  for j in 0..size1

      arr1 && arr1.push(txt && txt[j])

  end

  for i in 0..size1
      if arr1
      if arr1[i]==" " || arr1[i]=="@" || arr1[i]=="#" || arr1[i]=="{" || arr1[i]=="}" || arr1[i]=="(" || arr1[i]==")" || arr1[i]=="[" || arr1[i]=="]" || arr1[i]=="." || arr1[i]==";" || arr1[i]=="," || arr1[i]=="%" || arr1[i]=="&" || arr1[i]=="*" || arr1[i]=="!" || arr1[i]=="?" || arr1[i]=="$" || arr1[i]=="^" || arr1[i]==":" || arr1[i]=="-" || arr1[i]=="/"
        count=count+1
        arr1 && arr1[i]=""
      end
      end
  end
  temp=arr1 && arr1.join
  final1=temp.gsub(/\s+/, "").downcase

  ref.compact_string=final1
  ref.save
  return 1

  end

  def string_check(first_name)
  count =0;
  temp1=first_name
  supplied_val=temp1

  flag=100
  puts "Entered in string_check method"
  @employees=Employee.all
  t1=Employee.all.count
  puts t1
  @employees.each do |employee|  
    puts "in the loop"
    temp2=employee
    table_val=temp2.compact_string

    size1=supplied_val.to_s.length
    # size2=table_val.to_s.length


    puts table_val
    puts supplied_val

    arr1=Array.new


    for k in 0..size1

      arr1 && arr1.push(supplied_val && supplied_val[k])

    end


    for i in 0..size1
      if arr1
      if arr1[i]==" " || arr1[i]=="@" || arr1[i]=="#" || arr1[i]=="{" || arr1[i]=="}" || arr1[i]=="(" || arr1[i]==")" || arr1[i]=="[" || arr1[i]=="]" || arr1[i]=="." || arr1[i]==";" || arr1[i]=="," || arr1[i]=="%" || arr1[i]=="&" || arr1[i]=="*" || arr1[i]=="!" || arr1[i]=="?" || arr1[i]=="$" || arr1[i]=="^" || arr1[i]==":" || arr1[i]=="-" || arr1[i]=="/"
        count=count+1
        # puts count
        arr1 && arr1[i]=""
      end
      end
    end

    temp_st=arr1 && arr1.join
    final_st=temp_st.gsub(/\s+/, "").downcase



    if final_st==table_val
      puts "Entered in if"
      flag=0
      break
    else
      puts "Entered in else"
      flag=1
    end
  end

  puts @employees.count
  return flag

  end

def check_ultimate(get_val)
puts "Entered in check_ultimate method"
puts get_val
remove_data=get_val.to_s.chomp
#puts remove_data
si1=remove_data.to_s.length

puts si1

arr3=Array.new


    for p in 0..si1

      arr3 && arr3.push(remove_data && remove_data[p])

    end
    puts arr3
    puts "array end,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"


    count=0

    for i in 0..si1
      puts i
      if arr3
      #if arr3[i]=='@'
      if arr3[i]==" " || arr3[i]=="@" || arr3[i]=="#" || arr3[i]=="{" || arr3[i]=="}" || arr3[i]=="(" || arr3[i]==")" || arr3[i]=="[" || arr3[i]=="]" || arr3[i]=="." || arr3[i]==";" || arr3[i]=="," || arr3[i]=="%" || arr3[i]=="&" || arr3[i]=="*" || arr3[i]=="!" || arr3[i]=="?" || arr3[i]=="$" || arr3[i]=="^" || arr3[i]==":" || arr3[i]=="-" || arr3[i]=="/"
        count=count+1
        puts count
        arr3 && arr3[i]=""
      end
      end
    end

    temp_st_two=arr3 && arr3.join
    final_st_two=temp_st_two.gsub(/\s+/, "").downcase

    puts final_st_two
    puts "..............the ajax string"
    return final_st_two
 end
end
```

My view file is:

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet"    href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>


  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").keyup(function(){
    var box = document.getElementById("tags");
    document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML = box.value;
    $.getScript('/employees/new?pt=' + encodeURIComponent(box.value))
  });
  });

  $(function() {
  var availableTags=<%= @firstname_array.inspect.html_safe %>;

  availableTags.toString();
  document.getElementById("aaa").innerHTML = availableTags;
  // document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML = availableTags;

  $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags
  });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>


<div class="ui-widget">
<hr>
<%= form_for @emp do |f| %>
Firstname: <%= f.text_field :firstname, id: 'tags'  %></br></br>
<%= f.submit %>
<%end%>
<hr>

<h5><%=@msg%></h5>
<h3>Display all employee information</h3></br>
<% if !@emps.blank? %>
<% for item in @emps %>
    <%= item.firstname %> </br>
<%end%>
<%else%>
<%end%>

</div>

<div id="abc"></div>
<div id="aaa"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: no one is answering ...is it weird question??? LOL

Comment: It is a weird question. You should write down your expected output. You cannot easily call javascript functions from controllers.

Comment: I have mentioned what I expect in my problem description..Did you ever go through it? My problem is that I am not getting what I want.What else to describe!!! @BlairAnderson

Comment: the javascriipt autocomplete library used here works on an array of available names. Now I want to create a new array of string from my database each time during the keystroke in search box in controller and want to pass this array to the javascript function in view each time on keystroke from controller.